# How to work with signals from QTableWidget cell with cellWidget set

Tags: qt, signals, qtablewidget

I've got a `QTableWidget` with some columns inside.

Due to my needs I set `QComboBox` inside some columns and fill them with necessary data.

```
void settingsDialog::onAddFieldButtonClicked()
{
    fieldsTable->setRowCount(++rowCount);
    combo = new QComboBox();
    combo->addItem(QString("Choose from list..."));
    foreach( int height, heightsAvailable)
        combo->addItem(QString("%1").arg(height));
    fieldsTable->setCellWidget(rowCount-1, 3, combo);
    // etc for other columns ...
}
```

The question is how to catch signals from these combo boxes if they were changed?

I want to know `row` and `col` of changed widget (combo box) and the value which was set.

I've tried all available signals which are mentioned in Qt docs for `QTableWidget`, but they work only if cell doesn't have widget inside it.

 Is there a simple and Qt-way to get what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of handling a signal from the table, you can handle `currentIndexChanged` signal from combo box itself.

```
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
combo->addItem(QString("Choose from list..."));
combo->addItem(QString("first item"));
combo->setProperty("row", ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1);
combo->setProperty("column", 0);
connect(combo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(OnComboIndexChanged(const QString&)));
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 0, combo);
```

And in the slot, you can use `sender()` to identify the combo box which emitted the signal.

```
void MainWindow::OnComboIndexChanged(const QString& text)
{
    QComboBox* combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(sender());
    if (combo)
    {
        qDebug() << "row: " << combo->property("row").toInt();
        qDebug() << "column: " << combo->property("column").toInt();
    }
}
```