# Getting QTableWidgetItem out of cellWidget()'s QCheckBox

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qcheckbox

I'm storing QCheckBox in QTableWidget, in following way:

```
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(checkBox);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
widget->setLayout(layout);
tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, 2, widget);
```

Then, I catch `stateChanged()` of the `checkBox`:

```
connect( checkBox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxStateChanged(int)) );
void MainWindow::checkBoxStateChanged(int)
{
    QCheckBox * box = qobject_cast< QCheckBox * >( sender() );
    if( !box ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, I can get to `QTableWidget` – it is `box->parent()->parent()->parent()`. Object before that, i.e. `box->parent()->parent()`, is `qt_scrollarea_viewport` (that's `objectName()`). I've searched children of the "viewport", and there's `16` `QWidgets` – the number of rows in my table. However, their children are only `QHBoxLayout` and `QCheckBox`. There apparently is no reference to `QTableWidgetItem` – it looks like if I were in some parallel object hierarchy, and `QTableWidgetItem` is in other hierarchy. Is that true? How to get the item?

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [How to work with signals from QTableWidget cell with cellWidget set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484784/how-to-work-with-signals-from-qtablewidget-cell-with-cellwidget-set)

Adapted to you case:

```
void MainWindow::checkBoxStateChanged(int)
{
    QCheckBox * box = qobject_cast< QCheckBox * >( sender() );
    if (box)
    {
        int row = box->property("row").toInt();
        int column = box->property("column").toInt();
        QTableWidgetItem* item = tableWidget->item(row, column);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I move rows of the table. Would have to reflect the moves also on comboBox objects.